# Debugging / Logging to the cloud in PHP

Tags: php

Often times, I am out of the office without SSH.
And I want to debug a variable in PRODUCTION but I don't want to use functions like `var_dump`, `file_put_contents` to dump into the HTML body or write to my filesystem which I cannot access outside of the office.

Is there any way I can dump these variables using a GET or POST request to the cloud?  Are there any services that offer this?

Comment: You can log stuff to something like Bugsnag: https://www.bugsnag.com/

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks for this.  Does this tool only report errors?  
Or can I log any variables into their console as well? 

Example
`$bugsnag->log($someVariable);`

Comment: "To the cloud" doesn't really mean much - I mean, Google Docs has an API, so you could log to that if you wanted to, and that's "in the cloud". I suspect what you're really asking is "is there a service designed for this purpose", but [as discussed in the help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), questions asking for recommendations aren't considered "on topic" here.

Comment: @ParkBroom What you'd be able to do is something like `$bugsnag->notifyException(new LogDebugInfoException($data));`. `LogDebugInfoException` would be a custom exception type you create just for this.

Comment: @IMSoP yes, what I'm really asking if for a recommendation.  I'm aware I can use a mail function and mail the logs like that.  Or like you said - Google Docs API.

Comment: @ceejayoz thank you.  that would be perfect in my case.

Comment: @ParkBroom In that case, it's [definitely off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), sorry. To quote that page's reasoning: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." In other words, if we leave this open, there'll soon be dozens of answers with people linking to their favourite service - or one they have a vested interest in you using - and that's a type of content this site has decided to discourage.

Comment: @IMSoP I understand but where else would I find good advice on such a particular case?  I am not asking for the "best programming book" here.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using [monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) ?

> Monolog sends your logs to files, sockets, inboxes, databases and various web services. See the complete list of handlers below. Special handlers allow you to build advanced logging strategies.

You can literally log anything to anywhere, with a simple `$logger->error("bla bla bla")` call.

Here is an example where monolog is used to log messages from PHP to Slack:

https://www.sitepoint.com/logging-with-monolog-from-devtools-to-slack/

Comment: great idea.  I was unaware you can log messages to Slack like that

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using PHP XDebug - Remote debugging - https://xdebug.org/docs/remote

http://www.drupalonwindows.com/en/content/remote-debugging-production-php-applications-xdebug

Comment: thanks for this but I don't think this can log ajax calls or cronjobs that effectively w xdebug.  I need something I can log and throw it up to the cloud.